# Which ojdbc driver I could use for Oracle 12cR2 and JDK 11 application

Tags: java-11, ojdbc

**Question:**
What exact ojdbc driver should I use for: Oracle 12cR2 (12.2) with JDK 11

**Reference:**
I am referring https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html#01_01

[image]

Which says for ojdbc8.jar.
Now there are multiple versions released of ojdbc8.

The one which is release with Oracle 12.2 is not compatible with JDK11. (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-ucp-122-downloads.html)

The one which is released with Oracle 19c (19.3) is compatible with JDK11 (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-19c-downloads.html)

So I cannot find a clear explanation of using ojdbc jar to be used with Oracle 12.2 and JDK11.
Can I use ojdbc8 jar released with Oracle 19c for Oracle 12.2/12cR2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use 19c JDBC driver with Oracle Database 12.2. 
Please see the below in [FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) that shows the JDBC driver and the database compatibility.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw this table which says JDBC 19c driver works with 12.2. But I got confused, as it also says JDBC 12.2 and JDBC 11.2.0.4 drivers could also be used with Oracle 19c db. Is it true? Do JDBC 12.2 and JDBC 11.2.0.4 drivers work with Oracle 19c?  (I understand it will work for JDK 8 only, and this is a different question but related to the original one to get more clarification)

Comment: Yes, the old JDBC drivers 12.2 and 11.2.0.4 are forward compatible and works with the Oracle Database 19c. Yes, as you can see in the FAQ table (your post), 12.2 and later versions work with JDK8. and you do need JDK8.